# How to get Daylight Saving into a Date Arithmetic Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel to calculate the times of a series of events that occur a certain number of hours offset from a starting time.  I want the results to show in my local time.

My time zone will go off DST on November 1 at 02:00 but the results are not reflecting the change.

Is there a way to incorporate local time zone and DST into Excel date-time expressions?

Comment: Check out [Daylight Savings Time](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DaylightSavings.htm). A search for "excel daylight savings" gives you many other possibilities.

Comment: [so] duplicate: [How do you determine Daylight Savings Time in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/130877)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a non-VBA solution, you could use a formula to create a time offset dependent on whether the date in question falls on a DST day. In the UK this is a simpler problem for me, but with the US standard (second sunday in March and first sunday in November) it's a little more hassle.

I don't know quite how your current formulas work or how frequent they are, but an offset you could add to them would calculate something like this:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(My_Date,3)<>6,0,
  IF(
    AND(
      Month(My_Date)=11,
      My_Date-EOMONTH(My_Date,-1)<=7),
    1,
    IF(
      AND(
        Month(My_Date)=3,
        My_Date-EOMONTH(My_Date,-1)>7,
        My_Date-EOMONTH(My_Date,-1)<=14,
      -1,
      0)
   )
 )
```

Basically, we check if the date is a Sunday. If not, the offset is zero. If so, check whether it's November and within 7 days of the end of the previous month, and in that case the offset is +1. Otherwise, check whether it's March and 7-14 days from the end of the previous month. If so, the offset is -1.

In absence of more information about your current formulae, the above solution is only designed to consider whole days, and it sounds like your problem is more time-specific. The above formula should still hold, but might need 1/24 added here or there for it to only trigger in the exact instance you want it to.

Comment: I think I can do this, with the use of the hours tweak.  Thanks!